# summernote: how to add a "italic" button show it stay next to the bold and underline buttons?

Tags: wysiwyg, summernote

I am new to summernote. I hope to add a "italic" button next to the bold and underline buttons because it is such a common edit operation. I am unable to find examples of how to do it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's by default. But you can of course customize your own toolbar.

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    //[groupname, [button list]]
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']]
]
});
```

You can read more about custom toolbar [here](http://summernote.org/#/deep-dive/#custom-toolbar).

Comment: Be aware that this configuration will show only the listed buttons (so only 4 instead of the whole default toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

**By Design**:

As stated [here](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#custom-toolbar-popover) you can just configure summernote's toolbar by passing in a custom structure like this:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']]
  ]
});
```

NB: When overriding the toolbar structure you need to pass the whole toolbar and you cannot just override a single group (e.g. by initializing the array with just `['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']]`) as it would remove all the other actions

**Quick n dirty**:

- look for `['bold', 'underline' ....` in summernote.js
- add 'italic' between them

NB: it will be gone when you update. Surely it's better to copy the whole toolbar setting and replicate in your init options, adding whatever you see fit. But technically, it's there and it's gonna work. Line 9789 in my version. (Don't trust line numbers, look for the string.)

Comment: You should **never** edit vendor libraries to avoid breaking a project because of a simple dependency update/overwrite

Comment: I specifically included those first few words to avoid such comments. Again, yes, configuring properly is a better way; however, I let programmers decide how they want to play. I'm not into "you should never"-s.

Comment: True but at the same time your answer only offer that option who shouldn't really be offered in an environment like this where some people just follow the first answer blindly without really thinking about the consequences. I wouldn't have commented that if you had included that as an alternative solution to a more correct one (albeit incomplete) like MSvelander's.